# I'm creating a text adventure game that calls functions through user input. Inputting 1 at start() does call start_observe, but 2 calls start(). Why?

Tags: python-3.x, game-development

Here is the code with the available choices. I have no idea what's going on!

```
def start():
    slow_print("""_
    
        It's Monday, 9:33pm, August 4th, 2024.

        You lay in the back of an old truck headed ...yada yada... emember the last time you were awake.

        Enter (1) to observe your surroundings.
        Enter (2) to scream your lungs out.
        Enter (3) to climb out of the truck.
        Enter (4) to hear what's going on around you.
    
    _""", 1)

    choice = input("--> ")
    reset_console()
```

"1" calls start_observe() like it should, but "2" does not call start_scream(), I'm confused!

```
    if "1" in choice:
        start_observe()
    else:
        start()

    if "2" in choice:
        start_scream()
    else:
        start()

    if "3" in choice:
```

The only things I can think of would be that I'm not indenting correctly, or the functions aren't in the order they need to be in (this isn't it though I tested it).

Update, I changed it to this nested if statement style and it works, will I run into any further issues if I update this way?

```
choice = input("--> ")
    reset_console()
    
    if "1" in choice:
        start_observe()
    else:
        if "2" in choice:
            start_scream()
        else:
            if "3" in choice:
                start_climb()
            else:
                if "4" in choice:
                    start_hear()
                else:
                    start()
```

Also, thank you Luther for the help!

Update #2: Haha, okay I'm dumb. I did it this way instead after I realized else: if equals elif. Hahaha.

```
 if "1" in choice:
     start_observe()
 elif "2" in choice:
     start_scream()
 elif "3" in choice:
     start_climb()
 elif "4" in choice:
     start_hear()
 else:
     start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `choice` is `'2'`, and this code runs:

```
if "1" in choice: # False
    start_observe()
else: # This clause runs.
    start()
```

If this code is in the `start` function, it will start a recursive call before the code after it ever runs.

Comment: Oh my. I've written 800+ lines of code using this format. Did I just royally screw myself?

Comment: Basically, you need to delete all the `else: start()` statements (except the last one) and change all the `if`s (except the first) to `elif`. Maybe your text editor will let you do some search and replace.

Comment: I ended up doing nested if statements, so kinda the same right? It worked. Will I run into any problems later this way?

Comment: I'd consider it a problem that your indentation levels will get really huge. `elif` is syntactic sugar for `else: if` and doesn't require additional indentation. EDIT: You figured it out yourself in the update to your question.